# I get an error when I try to mount a disk to more that one mount point

Tags: mount, ntfs, disk

When I try and mount a disk to two mount mounts I get the following error:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

How do I prevent this message from displaying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot mount an NTFS volume in two places. This is by design to avoid FS corruption. You can, however, make a symlink from one location to the other.

Let's say you mount it at `/mnt/ntfs1` and want to make a second mount point at `/mnt/ntfs2`. You can symlink `/mnt/ntfs2` to `/mnt/ntfs1` as follows:

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/ntfs1 /mnt/ntfs2
```

Note the order in which the directories are given. The one where it is *successfully mounted* is first, and the place where you want to "mount" it is second.

Note that this is imperfect as using `cd ..` in shells will cause you to work within the wrong copy, but for file management programs, this should work, with one caveat,  from [here](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/FD_files/Getting_to_a_file.html):

> **NOTE**: There is the danger of a file becoming corrupted if more than one person tries to edit it at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

A safer way than symbolic links IMHO:

1. Mount the first mount like you used to do it
2. Create empty directories where you want the additional mount points to be, and mount to the additional mount points via the `--bind` option, for example:

   `sudo mount --bind /media/windows /home/your_user/windows`

Comment: Also a very good idea.