# XUbuntu: Unable to manually mount a disk drive

Tags: mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am trying to manually mount an NTFS drive to `/e`. `/e` has the permissions `drwxrwxr-x root root`

I tried the following commands, but none work. I get no error message, but the drive is not mounted:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /e
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /e 
sudo mount -t ntfs-3G /dev/sdb2 /e
```

If I click the drive in [Thunar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/thunar), it automatically mounts to `/media/joshua/Storage`.

When I execute `cat /proc/mounts`, I see the drive is mounted as follows:

`/dev/sdb2 /media/joshua/Storage fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0`

So I try doing that manually with the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t fuseblk /dev/sdb2 /e 
sudo mount -t fuseblk -o rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 /dev/sdb2 /e
```

but I get the following error:

`mount: /e: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

And I get the same error if I instead try to manually mount to `/media/joshua/Storage`.

The output of `blkid /dev/sdb` is:

```
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="b451b3b5-f03c-43d0-bd0d-2d564706a127" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

**How do I manually mount this drive to /e**?

Comment: Does /e actually exist, or are you attempting to "map" the NTFS partition to a non-existent drive letter (similar to what is very commonly done in Windows)? If /e does not exist that is the cause of the error. The mount command expects an actual (existing) mount point. To verify that mount is failing because of the mount point, attempt to mount to an existing directory.

Comment: `/e` exists and has the permissions indicated in the first paragraph: `drwxrwxr-x root root`

Comment: What is the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdb?`?  Edit your question with the output.

Comment: @Terrance: Updated

Comment: `fuseblk` isn't a real mount type - it just means that the filesystem is FUSE. `ntfs-3g` is correct, but (IIRC) NTFS filesystems get mounted exclusively by default, so you can't mount them on another location until you unmount the first one. https://askubuntu.com/a/200965/158442

Comment: @mura: I unmounted it from /media/joshua/Storage before trying to mount it to /e. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JoshuaD There is a ? after the `/dev/sdb` so it shows all the partitions.

Comment: Understood. Somehow this problem went away. I'm not sure what I did but restart the system (which I had already done) and try everything again, but right now I am able to mount things manually, and also do the automatic mounts in /etc/fstab with no problem.